# Regex to match abc OR a OR c

Tags: python, regex

Say I am considering patters which are matched by regexes `A` and `C`.  I am searching for patterns which match either `A` or `C` alone, OR `A` joined to `C` by some joining pattern `B`, i.e. `ABC`.

I could almost do `[AC(ABC)]`, but I would like to be able to name groups `A` and `C` and extract them once matched which would give an error here since I can't have multiple groups with the same name.

EDIT:

Since it seems people are getting confused, here is an example with my current scenario.  I am looking for numbers which may be expressed as mixed fractions, i.e. `1 1/2`.  However I need to be able to match either `1 1/2`, `1` or `1/2`.  This would correspond to `A = "\d+"`, `B=" "` and `C="\d+/\d+"`.

Note that this is a simplified case of my actual application, due to massive amounts of inconsistencies in the data I'm parsing, the actual regexes for A, B and C that I'm dealing with are quite a bit more complex.

Comment: So, that should be something ike [`\b(abc|a|c)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/IG1IRz/1) but without `a` and `c` repetition?

Comment: @barny won't that just match `ABC` or `AC`?  I don't want to match `AC` and that doesn't match `A` or `C` alone.

Comment: You can build it up from its subpieces: `A = r'...'; B = r'...'; C = r'...'; regex = '|'.join([A, C, A+B+C])`.

Comment: @chepner I forgot to mention I've named groups `A` and `C`, how would it react if I have multiple groups in the full regex with the same name as would happen if I did that?

Comment: @barny that doesn't match `C` alone though.

Comment: @PGmath I'm not sure; I think the groups will be numbered according to which branch ends up matching.

Comment: It is kind of confusing to me. I believe it would be helpful if you posted some samples of what matches and what does not.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I added an example.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without repeating the components.

Comment: @chepner it doesn't work, it throws an error that there are multiple groups with the same name.

Comment: "I realize I could do `[AC(ABC)]`"?? No you can't, you clearly don't know what that regex is doing. Please provide a sample input and the desired output. Presenting an XY Problem is hurting your question's credibility.

Comment: Then you'll have to use different names, and check which names are defined in the resulting match object.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I did provide a sample...  I reworded my presentation after trying chepner's proposal as well.

Comment: Sorry, you must have missed the critical sentence, once again: "Please provide a sample input and the desired output."

Comment: You really need to use the regexps separately or joined with `|`  (then use PyPi regex to allow multiple identically named groups). `(\d+)(?:\s(?1)/(?1)+|/(?1))?` [is too exotic](https://regex101.com/r/Tu41Ny/1) (and will only work with Python PyPi `regex` module) and will probably not be useful since your examples are oversimplified.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus how is "I need to be able to match either `1 1/2`, `1` or `1/2`" not a valid example of what I want in a regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't post my exact code and entire extensive problem here.  It would probably get closed as "too localized" anyhow.  Instead of throwing the XY problem at me, you could assume that I know what I'm trying to do and have correctly phrased it in the abstract portion of my question.  That is, given named regex groups `A`, `B` and `C`, I want to match any of the following regexes: `A`, `C`, `ABC`.

Comment: What about `(\d+\s+\d+/\d+|\d+|\d+/\d+)`? I.e., just give all three formats as alternatives.

Comment: ```str1 = '1 1/2 or 1 or 1/2 or 322';
str1.match(/(\d*\s?\d+\/\d+\s?\d*)|(\d+\/\d+)|\d+/g)
```

it will return ```["1 1/2 ", "1", " 1/2 ", "322"]```

if it is okay for you, we can improve this 

it it is not please give me example data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser approach rather than low-level regex might allow you to solve the problem at a more abstract level i.e. in a general purpose/flexible way, for example, using PyParsing:

```
import pyparsing as pp

digits  = pp.Word(pp.nums)            # a string of digits (could be the entire number, or a part of it)
fraction= digits + "/" + digits
number_with_fraction = digits + fraction
number =  (number_with_fraction("numfrac") ^ fraction("frac") ^ digits("integer") ) +pp.Regex("$")("EndOfInput")
    
for ntext in [
            "1",
            "1/2",
            "11 1/2",
        ]:
    print( f"Parsing {ntext=}" )
    parsed = number.parseString(ntext)
    print(repr(parsed))
```

Result:

```
Parsing ntext='1'
(['1', ''], {'integer': ['1'], 'EndOfInput': ['']})
Parsing ntext='1/2'
(['1', '/', '2', ''], {'frac': [(['1', '/', '2'], {})], 'EndOfInput': ['']})
Parsing ntext='11 1/2'
(['11', '1', '/', '2', ''], {'numfrac': [(['11', '1', '/', '2'], {})], 'EndOfInput': ['']})
```

**UPDATE**

Making my simple parser a bit more complete, I've added calculating a single numeric value from the optional number, optional fraction. To do this I defined a `setParseAction` for each of the patterns which does the appropriate calculation:

```
import pyparsing as pp

digits               = pp.Word(pp.nums).setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))            # a string of digits (could be the entire number, or a part of it)

fraction             = digits + "/" + digits
fraction.setParseAction(lambda t: t[0]/t[2])

number_with_fraction = digits + fraction
number_with_fraction.setParseAction(lambda t: t[0]+t[1])

number               =  (number_with_fraction("numfrac") ^ fraction("frac") ^ digits("integer") ) +pp.Regex("$")("EndOfInput")
    
for ntext in [
            "1",
            "1/2",
            "11 1/2",
        ]:
    print( f"Parsing {ntext=}" )
    parsed = number.parseString(ntext)
    print(repr(parsed))
```

Result:

```
Parsing ntext='1'
([1, ''], {'integer': [1], 'EndOfInput': ['']})
Parsing ntext='1/2'
([0.5, ''], {'frac': [0.5], 'EndOfInput': ['']})
Parsing ntext='11 1/2'
([11.5, ''], {'numfrac': [11.5], 'EndOfInput': ['']})
```

Comment: Nice answer - more discussion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911824/how-can-fractional-number-expressions-be-parsed-using-pyparsing/3914732#3914732

Comment: @PaulMcG Thanks - this was my first try of PyParsing, wasn’t intended to be a “solution”, as I’m sure you can tell. Thanks for the link, I may try to upgrade this closer to a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work:

```
(?P<mixed_fraction>(?P<integer>\b\d+\b)? (?P<fraction>\b\d+\/\d+\b)?)
```

You'll just need to add logic which says "When `mixed_fraction` is a space then ignore"

https://regex101.com/r/crsHMc/1/